# For Loop in SQL Server 2005 Express?

Tags: sql, database, loops, sql-server-2005-express

I have a program using SQL Server 2005 Express and I need some help looping through 2 tables to calculate inventory.

- `Table 1`: stores all products with the inventory total upon setup
- `Table 2`: stores the transactions against all products from table 1

How can I loop through all items in table 2 and subtract that amount from table 1 counts?

If I have my query like this then I get data for each product

```
SELECT 
     ii.ItemNum, ii.ItemName, ii.OzOnHand
FROM 
     dbo.InventoryItems ii
INNER JOIN 
     dbo.InventoryLog il ON ii.ItemNum = il.InvItemNum
WHERE 
     ii.active = 1
```

I need each occurrence from table 2 to be subtracted from table 1's total amount

Comment: When you have a query to solve and you think "I'll use a loop for that" - step back and think again. SQL is optimized to deal with sets, not looping through one row at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a join to an aggregated table (I think that is the best way to understand it):

```
SELECT ii.ItemNum, ii.ItemName, ii.OzOnHand, ii.OzOnHand - coalesce(il.cnt, 0)
FROM dbo.InventoryItems ii LEFT JOIN
     (select il.InvItemNum, sum(OzRemoved) as cnt
      from dbo.InventoryLog il
      group by il.InvItemNum
     ) il
     ON ii.ItemNum = il.InvItemNum
WHERE ii.active = 1;
```

The subquery groups everything in the log and counts the number of entries.  If each entry could affect more than one item, then you would use something like `sum(cnt) as cnt` instead of `count(*)`.

Then, the query uses a `left outer join`.  This type of join ensures that all inventory items remain, even those with nothing in the log.  Finally, the count is subtracted from what is available in set up.  The `coalesce()` is to handle the situation where there are no matches in the log table.  To avoid getting `NULL`, the `NULL` is turned into a `0`.

Comment: This is very close. Instead of subtracting the `count` of items that match in the InventoryLog table i need the number from that tables `OzRemoved` column. So the query you suggested removed 9 from the `OzOnHand` instead of the sum from `OzRemoved` in that same table

Comment: @Matt to be fair, your question didn't even mention a column called `OzRemoved`, never mind hint that this is the "count" you were after. Anyway I suspect you can take Gordon's answer from here, and just change `COUNT(*)` to `SUM(OzRemoved)`.

Comment: Yeas i am sorry @aaron, i just realized i didnt have that field in the question. I changed that before you commented and i think i have the correct numbers now...need to verify with a few more samples

Comment: @Matt of course, that assumes that rows get removed out of there periodically, otherwise if today you have 2 removed, and you subtract 2, then tomorrow you subtract those 2 again...

Comment: @AaronBertrand that is a good point. Its a log table so probably not :(